# Convert values in a List of Maps with Streaming API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of maps with non distinctive keys and like to modify each map value with *Streaming API*. The result should be a new list, the original one has to remain unchanged.

Example data:

```
// [ {jpg=firstImage.jpg, png=firstImage.png}, {jpg=secondImage.jpg, png=secondImage.png} ]
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("jpg", "firstImage.jpg");
map1.put("png", "firstImage.png");
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("jpg", "secondImage.jpg");
map2.put("png", "secondImage.png");
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);
```

Let's assume I want to convert the filename to upper case. With distinctive values I could do the following:

```
Map<String, String> copy = list.stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().toUpperCase()));
```

But *flatMap* does not work when keys aren't distinctive, and it would destroy my `List<Map<String, String>>` structure. I know that the structure is bad, but I can't change it.

Expected outcome:

```
// [ {jpg=FIRSTIMAGE.JPG, png=FIRSTIMAGE.PNG}, {jpg=SECONDIMAGE.JPG, png=SECONDIMAGE.PNG} ]
```

I'd like to achieve this with Streaming API and avoid nested loops if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `flatMap`, because this way you would concat all Entries in a single Stream and thus loose the possibility to get them back.

You need to convert each individual element from your `List`, like this for example:

```
  List<Map<String, String>> result = list.stream()
            .map(map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                  Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                  e -> e.getValue().toUpperCase())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
    // [{jpg=FIRSTIMAGE.JPG, png=FIRSTIMAGE.PNG}, {jpg=SECONDIMAGE.JPG, png=SECONDIMAGE.PNG}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an option

```
    list.forEach(map -> map.replaceAll((t, f) -> f.toUpperCase()));
```

I am modifying the existing maps in your list. And it’s not using streams.

Edit: Thanks to VGR for the great simplification.

Edit: Since you need to leave your original structure unmodified, [Eugene’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43849203/5772882) is fine. You may also apply `replaceAll()` on a copy. One example:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
    list.replaceAll(m -> {
                Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>(m);
                newMap.replaceAll((t, f) -> f.toUpperCase());
                return newMap;
            });
```

Or yet a different approach, this one with a stream:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> result = list.stream()
            .map(m -> {
                Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>(m);
                newMap.replaceAll((t, f) -> f.toUpperCase());
                return newMap;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which to prefer, I’d say it’s mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's cleaner than nested streams. But I forgot to add that the original structure has to remain unchanged.

Comment: Actually it has got nested streams too. Your requirement shouldn’t be surprising, and I cannot suggest anything better than [Eugene’s solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43849203/5772882).

Comment: list.stream().forEach can be written as just `list.forEach`.  (Actually, I believe the entire statement can be shortened to `list.forEach(map -> map.replaceAll((t, f) -> f.toUpperCase()))`.)